# Check discord bot's permissions so it wont crash

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im making a dumb discord bot, but it crashes everytime when he's muted or in timeout.
How do i add a send messages permission check?

```
import discord
import random

TOKEN = "blahblahblah"

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("{0.user} is now online!".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if 'blah' in message.content or client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        print(message.author, ":", message.content)
        if random.randint(1,2) == 2:
            await message.channel.send('blah?')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('blah!')
client.run(TOKEN)
```

When he's in timeout and trying to send a message, python gives me a 403 forbidden error.

All of the solutions i found in the internet were confusing, most of them didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch exceptions like this:

```py
try:
    await message.channel.send("blah")
except discord.Forbidden:
    print("Bot is missing permissions")
```

I highly recommend using `commands.Bot()` instead of `discord.Client()` as it comes with several benefits such as error handling, support for the commands extension, and checks among other things.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

Comment: I'm not sure why they would need `commands.Bot` here, `discord.Client` suffices for their current use case.

Comment: While the code *currently* can use discord.Client(), the class is insufficient for most proper use cases and will need to be changed if they plan on adding anything more than that. Cogs, among other features, require using commands.Bot and allow for a much more maintainable codebase.